# Should I use "has" or "have" for "Is there any field or fields that ____ this property?"

Tags: grammatical-number

I have no idea what a good title for this question should be.  I'm asking a database guy about a problem with our data.  I'm considering phrasing it this way:

> Is there any other field or fields that have this property?

Is "have" correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no point in confusing yourself and others by saying "field or fields" in the first place.  Just pick a plurality and stick with it:

- Is there any other field that has this property?
- Are there any other fields that have this property?

You should get a "yes, there is one other" or "yes, there are 5 others" or "no, there is no other field" as the answer to either question.